# Does Simpy support optimized dynamic resource distributon across multiple nodes?

Tags: dynamic, resources, allocation, simpy

I have 2 nodes 0 and 1 and in total there are 12 resources which will server in the nodes 0 and 1. Is there a method in Simpy to schedule the 12 resources across nodes 0 and 1 so that the average total processing time of an item through node 0 followed by node 1 is minimized. From time to time resources can move from one node to another for serving. Attached is the code where I have come up with a static distribution of 5 resources in node 0 and 7 resources in node 1. How to make it dynamic with time ?

```
import numpy as np
import simpy

def interarrival():
    return(np.random.exponential(20))

def servicetime():
    return(np.random.exponential(60))


def servicing(env, servers_1):
    i = 0
    while(True):
        i = i+1
        yield env.timeout(interarrival())
        print("Customer "+str(i)+ " arrived in the process at "+str(env.now))
        state = 0
        env.process(items(env, i, servers_array, state))

def items(env, customer_id, servers_array, state):
    with servers_array[state].request() as request:
        yield request
        t_arrival = env.now
        print("Customer "+str(customer_id)+ " arrived in "+str(state)+ "  at "+str(t_arrival))
        yield env.timeout(servicetime())
        t_depart = env.now
        print("Customer "+str(customer_id)+ " departed from "+str(state)+ "  at "+str(t_depart))
        if (state == 1):
            print("Customer exits")
        else:
            state = 1
            env.process(items(env, customer_id, servers_array, state))
            

env = simpy.Environment()
servers_array = []
servers_array.append(simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 5))
servers_array.append(simpy.Resource(env, capacity = 7))
env.process(servicing(env, servers_array))
env.run(until=2880)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the resources, start each node with a capacity of 12 and use the delay from your last question to delay some of the resources from each node so the total active resources is the total you want.  Otherwise you may want to start looking at containers and stores which will allow you to move a resource from one node to another.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Containers and Stores might be more appropriate for this setting. Let me have a look.